# sony smartwatch sw2 broadcast global notification

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

My Control Extension looks good. But I need some notification mechanism sometimes.

I had tested the http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/12/26/using-both-the-control-notification-apis-for-customised-uis-in-your-smartwatch-2-extension-code/. but the extension becomes a NOTIFICATION. when I set  LAUNCH_MODE to NOTIFICATION.

My question is …

1. Do I have to write two apps? one control and one notification that interact with each other. But when I add two extensions in my application. There is only one exist. How to set two apps in one project?
2. If I want to keep my original control and just send notification message through normal sw2 notification mechanism. Just pupup a message box , no other menu action. Is there any mechanism like this?

Answer (score 0):

Answers are below:

1. If you follow the example above, you should have two extensions in your project, one Control and one Notification.  It will start in the Notification view and then when you press the menu item it launches the Control.  You can't have both running at once unfortunately, only one at a time.
2. There is no mechanism like this.  If you want to receive notifications in a Control extension you'll have to create your own mechanism to receive the messages.